# why does putting a space between command output and redirection character cause an error?

Tags: bash, redirect, while-loop

I have a question about using several ways of redirecting input to `while` loop. If I want to feed contents of a file, I can do it adding `< filename.txt`, `< <(cat filename.txt)` and `<<< $(cat filename.txt)` to `done` statement at the end. The question is, why does the second option require the redirection character `<` be right next to the parenthesis, other it gives an error, while it doesnt matter for the first and the third option, whether there is a space between the less-than sign and the parenthesis?

Comment: `<( )` is it's own syntax, called Process Substitution. It is a temp file, a `fifo` to be specific, `ls -l <(:)` should show you what I mean. and in order to read from a file you need the  `<` sign, which is a `redirection`.

Comment: Because a subshell operator (`(`) is not expected after a here-document operator (`<<`).

Comment: It is a tokenization issue. `< (` is tokenized as two tokens, `<` and `(` and since the `<` is a redirection operator, normally a file or descriptor is expected following it. Definitely a `( commands )`, which would create a subshell to execute the commands between the parenthesis, is not expected.

Comment: jetchisel's comment answered it more thoroughly! I have seen Process Substitution mentioned, when I was trying to find the answer, but I wasnt aware that it is a file created by this special syntax, and thus should be treated as such while redirecting. Thank you!